# Access Puppet built-in variables from a custom provider

Tags: ruby, puppet

There are built-in global variables, which can be accessed from a manifest or template. Like $serverip for the IP address of the master. I know how to call Facter, but some built-ins are not represented by any Facter's "facts". How can they be accessed from a custom provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more feedback from the OP it became clear that this is not about `master` information from global variables, but "implicit facts" with agent configuration instead.

The agent can very simply use its configuration from a global hash.

```
port = Puppet['masterport']
master_host = Puppet['server']
```

Comment: This is simple indeed, by any measure :). Thank you, Frank!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the agent transfers fact values to the master, so that during manifest compilations, you can use the values as you described.

The agent itself (and by extension, the types and providers) can access these values directly.

```
value = Facter.value('serverip')
```

This should be possible in virtually all contexts on the agent side (including custom facts), because the Puppet agent will *always* load Facter, making resolution directly available.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work neither for 'servername' nor for 'serverip'. When called on a remote client (from provider code), it returns an empty string. And so does Facter when run from command line. Hence the question :).

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm still on Puppet 2.7. In the newer versions, there's something called $server_facts.

Comment: Oh from the `master`. I think you're out of luck there. The agent can only use information that is part of the catalog or retrieved by Facter. So you would need to manually pass the data to your type instances as parameters. Resource defaults make this kind of stunt much more feasible.

Comment: Er, so either to 
- litter the custom types with parameters, whose only purpose is to make sure the variable makes its way to the catalog
- parse puppet.conf, vulgar but simple

Comment: Parsing the agent's `puppet.conf` will yield no reliable information about master configuration, though. If you are after agent side configuration settings, that is yet another matter. That should be a new Question then I suppose.

Comment: In my case, I just need the server name and the 'masterport'. If an agent had connected to the master successfully, that should be reliable enough :). That's why I'm a bit confused: the agent _knows_ these two things, so I thought there must be a way to just use variables that are already defined by parsing the very same puppet.conf :)))

Answer (score 1):

To wrap it up, the following dumps the 'global' settings into a human-readable commented config-file format, for those wondering which settings are available (those accessible with Puppet['*setting*']):

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'puppet'
irb(main):002:0> Puppet.initialize_settings
irb(main):003:0> puts Puppet.settings.to_config
```